# Setting session timezone with spring jdbc oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc, timezone

I have a spring/jdbc/oracle 10g application.
The Oracle server database timezone is set to GMT + 2 JVM timezone is GMT + 2 (even though it doesn't matter in my case).

I have a stored procedure that performs some date operations. The problem is that session timezone is different(GMT) than database timezone even though I do not set session timezone explicit in my code/configuration.

As far as I know the session timezone is by default equal to database timezone. Any idea why is the session timezone different than database timezone or how can I configure it in spring configuration (org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Which session do you mean?  Oracle connection session, or HTTP session? The former, I assume?

Comment: This solve your problem? I need to do the same on MySQL and I'm still looking for how to do it!

Comment: I have questions/posts that stay in this DEAD mode!! No answers, no confirmations, no speculations!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way is to use `DelegatingDataSource`, retrieve `OracleConnection` object from the original data source and call `OracleConnection.setSessionTimeZone()` with the appropriate parameter.

C3P0 code looks like:

```
private Object[] timeZoneArgs = new Object[] { "Europe/Berlin" };

@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = super.getConnection();
    try {
        final Method setSessionTimeZoneMethod = OracleConnection.class.getMethod("setSessionTimeZone", String.class);
        final C3P0ProxyConnection castCon = (C3P0ProxyConnection) conn;
        castCon.rawConnectionOperation(setSessionTimeZoneMethod, C3P0ProxyConnection.RAW_CONNECTION, timeZoneArgs);
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("setSessionTimeZone failed " + e.getMessage());
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: can be simplified: `conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).setSessionTimeZone("UTC");`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by upgrading Oracle's JDBC drivers from v10.2.0.1.0 to v11.2.0.3. No changes to my java code were required.

Source: [Spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?52305-How-to-set-the-connection-time-zone-%28Oracle-JdbcTemplate-Session-Time-Zone-not-set%29&p=361898#post361898).

Answer (score 1):

In spring configuration, add below VM options before running the application:

```
-Duser.timezone=EDT
```

Also make sure your pom has latest jdbc driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```