# Setting connection timezone dynamically with Spring and c3p0 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, c3p0, spring-jdbc

I want to dynamically set the timezone for a MySQL JDBC connection with c3p0 as connection pool. To set time zone for a given MySQL JDBC connection I know I can use "SET time_zone = '+02:00';", but if I set this on a connection I get from the pool I assume the connection will have this time zone when it is being given back to the pool and given to a new request witch request a connection?!? Have I understood it correct?

If yes, how can I set dynamically in a way that the pooled connection is having its timezone reverted to original one (in my case I use UTC as default on MySQL and in the JCM through TimeZone.setDefault(UTC) during startup of my spring context).

Here is my code snippet from my (Report)Dao

```
public TrafficDuringDayGroupedByPhoneEvent countAllSummariesForTimeReport(Integer childId, Date start, Date end, MessageType type, TimeZone timezone) {


    Integer[] res = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    Session session = getSession();

    //SET time_zone = '+02:00';
    String sql = "select count(calls.d), d from (SELECT  start_time, \n"
            + "(case when hour(start_time) >= 6 and  hour(start_time) < 9 then 'morning'\n"
            + "when hour(start_time) >= 9 and  hour(start_time) < 15 then 'day'\n"
            + "when hour(start_time) >= 15 and  hour(start_time) < 21 then 'aft'\n"
            + "when hour(start_time) >= 21 and  hour(start_time) <= 24 then 'night'\n"
            + "when hour(start_time) < 6 then 'night' end) as d\n" + "FROM bpr_report_event b inner join ";

    ....
}
```

My question is similar to the one below, except that I want to set it dynamically per connection, not the same timezone as the guy in the question below does.

[Setting connection timezone with Spring and DBCP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970835/setting-connection-timezone-with-spring-and-dbcp-and-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a c3p0 ConnectionCustomizer which sets the time zone back to UTC onCheckin. See

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ConnectionCustomizer.html

http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers