# Cant connect to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I get a strange exception tryining to connect to local mysql database. I am bulding spring mvc application.

This is how I configured DriverManagerDataSource:

```
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("****");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("****");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}
```

Those are log details that I get trying to connect:

```
    root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value '�rodkowoeuropejski czas letni' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.CustomerRepositoryImpl.getAllCustomers(CustomerRepositoryImpl.java:35)
    com.packt.webstore.controller.HomeController.showCustomers(HomeController.java:36)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
```

I figured out that it must be some problem with mysql-connector-java. I changed the version from 6.0.3 to 5.1.39. I just changed the version in my pom.xml file

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What version of the Oracle's JDBC you're using?

Comment: Well, to use it you simply add that `dependency` tag to your `pom.xml` file and Maven will do all the work for you (if you're using Maven)

Comment: It seems that the problem you're having might have been related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805907/setting-session-timezone-with-spring-jdbc-oracle) too.

Comment: And this has not be solved yet?

Comment: It seems that it might have been a bug, so by upgrading the driver, the problem wouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it has been, should i add an answer to close the topic?

Comment: So do you recomend my to leave the 5.1.39 version? I though that mamby some line of code could fix the issue with the newest version. Using the older version seems to be half-measure.

Comment: If your work doesn't limit you to using certain versions of APIs you can pretty much always preffer to use the latest release.

Comment: I think you should check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970835/setting-connection-timezone-with-spring-and-dbcp-and-mysql) as well

Comment: @Przemek would you consider accepting and/or give feedback/points to the other questions you posted; you know it's the way this site works...

Answer (score 1):

Replace your jdbc url by 
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack errors.You should specify your time zone value.Add [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) is the same question.